# Second setInterval function is not invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I had a working script where it would perform ajax calls and update multiple areas of the page using jquery. I worked on a second set of code to create a script which would take a string like "2 Days 19:20", split it into Days, Hours and Minutes, then use setInterval to increment the string minute by minute. It worked on its own when there was just one setInterval function on the page.

Now, I've added this code to my main script, using unique variable and function names, and added the setInterval for this function such that my `$().ready` looks like this:

```
$(document).ready (function()
{   
    setInterval(function() {        
        Communicate_Server();
    }, ServerPollFrequency );

    setInterval(function() {        
        UpdateMyClock();
    }, ClockUpdateFreq );
});
```

The functions look like this:

```
function UpdateMyClock () {
    alert("Called");
    $('.showonline').each(function () {

        var cl = $(this).html();
         cl=SplitTime(cl);
         $(this).html(cl);
}

function SplitTime (TimeString) {
    ... 
}
```

The alert was added to debug the script. The issue is that the function `Communicate_Server();` works, however `UpdateMyClock()` is never called. `var ClockUpdateFreq=1;` is set prior to `$().ready`.

What could be causing this? If I need to provide more of my code, I will.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: None at all. It shows my ajax calls proceeding.

Comment: Your `UpdateMyClock ` has syntax errors...

Comment: @Droidzone -- Forgot to close your `.each()` loop.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I think my browser may have cached the script. The console didnt show any errors previously.

Comment: Try using firebug to investigate any error occurrence.

Comment: It's solved. Typo in my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot a } for UpdateMyClock !

```
function UpdateMyClock () {
    alert("Called");
    $('.showonline').each(function () {

        var cl = $(this).html();
         cl=SplitTime(cl);
         $(this).html(cl);
    });// CLOSE THE EACH
}// CLOSE UpdateMyClock

function SplitTime (TimeString) {
    ... 
}
```

An example of what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/FrYqE/1/

*NOTE*: use *console.log* for debug ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    function UpdateMyClock () {
        alert("Called");
        $('.showonline').each(function () {

            var cl = $(this).html();
             cl=SplitTime(cl);
             $(this).html(cl);
        });
    }
```